# Как обновить recyclerview при добавлении item?

Tags: android, recyclerview

При открытии Activity на сервер отправляется get-запрос(getComment) и в recyclerview выводится список с комментариями. При нажатии кнопки на сервер посылается post-запрос(addComment), после чего нужно, чтобы список с комментариями обновился, но при использовании `recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyAll();` или `recyclerView.getAdapter().notify();` выпадает ошибка `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify().` Как правильно обновить recyclerview после добавления комментария?

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Object> items;
    public static RequestInterface requestInterface;
    Button btnAddComment;
    EditText etComment;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
        etComment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_comment);
        btnAddComment = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add_comment);

        requestInterface = Controller.getApi();
        items = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, items);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        requestInterface.getComment(id).enqueue(new Callback <List<Comment>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call <List<Comment>> call, Response <List<Comment>> response) {
                items.addAll(response.body());
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call <List<Comment>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

            btnAddComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            AddComment addComment = new AddComment();
            addComment.setText(etComment.getText().toString());
requestInterface.addComment(addComment).enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyAll();
 }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во первых, для добавления нового итема, его нужно добавить в коллекцию, связанную с адаптером:

```
items.add(addComment);
```

Затем нужно обновить адаптер:

```
recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemInserted(items.size() - 1);
```